# Impact of message size on redis publish's performance

Tags: redis

Let's say currently I make 100 publish calls on a channel with each payload being a singleton list of some object.

Does merging these into a single publish call with payload being the list of 100 objects improve performance? (especially the load on redis' cpu)

Comment: Seems like something you could measure yourself on your actual hardware and with representative data, rather than expecting there to be an abstract always true answer.